# How can I retrieve the email confirmation status for the currently logged in user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

I need to determine whether or not a user has confirmed their email address or not.

I have tried using the below code and numerous iterations of usermanager, SigninManager, ApplicaitonUserManager, etc. but have had no luck.  I get the error "Too few arguments for UserManager" in the scenario below.

```
Dim emailstatus as string

If UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync=True then
emailstatus="confirmed"
ElseIf UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync=False Then
emailstatus="unconfirmed"
Else
End If
```

I just need to retrieve the IsEmailConfirmed status for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Have you tried [passing the user id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn497563(v=vs.108))?

Comment: @the_lotus I did try using the userid initially with no luck.  I am now trying: <br/>Dim manager1 = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))<br/>
     Dim currentUser = manager1.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId())<br/>
     Dim ConfirmationStatus As String = currentUser.EmailConfirmed<br/><br/> but I get an error saying that currentuser is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function i use to get the current logged user:

```
Private Function GetUser() As ApplicationUser
   Return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager).FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
End Function
```